# How to add comments to .dbc for CAN bus

Tags: embedded, protocols, can-bus

I am trying to figure out how to add comments to a .dbc file, but the DBC specification doesn't seem to address this.

I tried adding `//` and it seems to work, but I don't want to rely on undefined behaviour.

Comment: I believe it's parens with an asterisk ---  IE `(* Comment here *)`  -- Not answering until you verify lol  --  It's been a while since I worked with anything CanBus

Comment: It is clearly defined here: http://read.pudn.com/downloads766/ebook/3041455/DBC_File_Format_Documentation.pdf on page 2.  The question is not clearly on-topic for SO being essentially a configuration file, and not code.

Comment: @Clifford *being essentially a configuration file, and not code* --  While technically you are correct, think of them as plain text DLL files etc .. Even though it is called a configuration file, it acts like a programming language to help the program run.  Conversely, a `php.ini` file or `my.cnf` file aren't programming languages either, but there are plenty of questions (with upvotes I might add) that  positively contribute to 
 the SO community

Answer (score 4):

I haven't found any way to add comments at arbitrary locations in a DBC file (the `(* ... *)` notation is only for comments in the documentation describing the DBC file syntax), but based on the example at the end of http://read.pudn.com/downloads766/ebook/3041455/DBC_File_Format_Documentation.pdf I determined that you can at least put explanatory comments in the comments section of the database itself, using the `CM_` notation:

```
CM_ "This is an explanatory comment that must appear together with all the other
dbc object comments, but may span multiple lines within the quotes";
```

Comment: Updated [link](https://github.com/stefanhoelzl/CANpy/blob/master/docs/DBC_Specification.md#cm_). CM_ has to be used after the Message and Signal definition. BDC editors (like CANdb++) might not open if the comments is not in the right section